# Scheme - What is wrong with my attempt to extend this declaration?

Tags: scheme, environment, racket

This is a homework question.

**Question**
[image]

My attempt (the whole file): http://pastebin.com/TS6mByEj

If you search `let var = exp1 in body`, that's the function I need to extend according to the question.

When I test the sample code above, I get an error `apply-env: No binding for y`

> (eval "let x = 30
>                  in let x = -(x,1)
>                         y = -(x,2)
>                     in -(x,y)")

```
; The following is execution log

The-next-two-lines-shows-var-and-exp1
(x)
(#(struct:const-exp 30))

diff-exp
#(struct:var-exp x)
#(struct:const-exp 1)

diff-exp
#(struct:var-exp x)
#(struct:const-exp 2)

The-next-two-lines-shows-var-and-exp1
(x y)
(#(struct:diff-exp #(struct:var-exp x) #(struct:const-exp 1)) #(struct:diff-exp #(struct:var-exp x) #(struct:const-exp 2)))

diff-exp
#(struct:var-exp x)
#(struct:var-exp y)
```

I know this is really long language, but if anyone can kindly lead me to the right direction would be really really nice.

Thank you!

---

**UPDATE**

Right before I evaluate and hit the error, the new environment `env1` is like this

```
(#(struct:extend-env x #(struct:num-val 29) #(struct:extend-env x #(struct:num-val 30) #(struct:extend-env i #(struct:num-val 1) #(struct:extend-env v #(struct:num-val 5) #(struct:extend-env x #(struct:num-val 10) #(struct:empty-env))))))

#(struct:extend-env y #(struct:num-val 28) #(struct:extend-env x #(struct:num-val 30) #(struct:extend-env i #(struct:num-val 1) #(struct:extend-env v #(struct:num-val 5) #(struct:extend-env x #(struct:num-val 10) #(struct:empty-env)))))))
```

One of them is `#(struct:extend-env y #(struct:num-val 28)`. So `y` exists in the environment which it is going to be evaluated, except it is not part of the `car env1`. It is in `cdr env1`

Yet, my code relies on `car env1`....

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my answer because I misread your question, and my answer wouldn't have been of any help.

Comment: @KshitijMehta That's fine. You still took your time to reply :) let's hope somebody can give me a good head here!! Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got your finger on the problem, but your language suggests some conceptual problems. In particular, `env1` is not an environment, it's a list of environments. Why are you using `map`? What are you taking the `car` of the result? What happens if you run your interpreter on `"let in 5"` (ie, no variable bindings)?

Your use of `map` and `car` suggests to me that you're attempting to code on autopilot ("I have a list... `map` does stuff with lists!"). Either that or you're thinking that `extend-env` *changes* (mutates) the environment and `map` is a way of mutating it several times. But that's wrong.

My advice: think about what you want the environment to contain. Make a separate helper function for computing the new environment. Make it a simple recursive function: no higher-order helpers like `map` (yet). Write test cases for it. Once you get it working (ie, tested), see if it fits a pattern that you can use a higher-order function to simplify.